# Connecting boards

Tags: integrated-circuit, interconnect

This may be a totally newbee question, but it's so basic that I can't find a clear answer and I've already smoked one board...

I need to connect two boards (a radio receiver's SBUS signal to an RC helicopter mainboard), and the pins in the connectors are labeled as:

- SIG, 5V, GND
- S, -, +

on the respective boards.

Is it correct to connect:

- SIG to S,
- 5V to +,
- GND to -

Should be self-explanatory but the different order of the respecive pins is confusing me.

**Update**

The label + is on the radio receiver board, which is a [Redcon FT4X](https://www.gearbest.com/radios-receiver/pp_648346.html) - its description states:

> Mini 2.4GHz SBUS receiver supports 3.3 - 15V operating voltage

The motherboard is the one that comes with the [Eachine E160](https://www.eachine.com/Eachine-E160-6CH-Brushless-3D6G-System-Flybarless-RC-Helicopter-BNF-Compatible-with-FUTABA-S-FHSS-BNF(1-Battery)-p-1942.html).

Comment: That's how I'd hook them up, if that was all I knew about the boards. I would look into it more, though.

Comment: Not if "+" is only compatible with 3.3V or something less than 5V.